# Msi installer stopped working

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web, windows-installer

I previously installed a website on the server by running an msi package and everything worked fine. Now, when I try to run the same msi file (to Repair/Uninstall), I get a message:[image: Message 1]

When I click Cancel, I get the following message:
[image: Message 2]

Anybody has an idea what happened and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Can you browse (using Windows Explorer) to the "installation source" successfully?  And can you execute / read the file (outisd of the installer)?  It sounds distinctly like you've lost access (permission) to the file, or it has been moved.  However, this is not on topic for Stack Overflow.  Possibly on-topic for [SU].

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you run the MSI with logging enabled.  This can be done by using the /l*v C:\mylog.txt switch or by modifying the registry. The log will provide you with more precise information as to what is going wrong during the msi process.

The articles below describe how to enable logging and the logging process in more detail

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(v=WS.10).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372847(v=vs.85).aspx

Once you have the log you can use a set of MSI tools like the Orca installer database editor tool on the Windows SDK to correct any issues.

This is the link for Windows 7 SDK which contains the msi tools.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I found the problem and I want to share the solution:

After I installed the old version on the server, I changed the name of the msi file. Consequently, I could not run the old version to repair/update. I could not even install a newer version over the old version, as the installer needed the old msi to uninstall the old version.

When I changed back the filename of the old version, it allowed me to install the new version.

**CONCLUSION: Don't change the name of the msi file after installation.**